# Redhat 6 gui installation VS kickstart gives me different packages?

Tags: rhel6, kickstart

If i do the graphical install and select basic server + aide and screen i get a system with 535 installed packages.

If i look at the /root/anaconda-ks.cfg file in that freshly installed system i see:

```
%packages
@base
@console-internet
@core
@debugging
@directory-client
@hardware-monitoring
@java-platform
@large-systems
@network-file-system-client
@performance
@perl-runtime
@security-tools
@server-platform
@server-policy
@system-admin-tools
pax
python-dmidecode
oddjob
sgpio
certmonger
pam_krb5
krb5-workstation
nscd
pam_ldap
nss-pam-ldapd
perl-DBD-SQLite
aide
screen
```

If i then install a NEW system using a kickstart only containing those packages i get 620 installed packages.

So basicly my question is why does the system install almost 100 more packages when using kickstart compared to the GUI installation when the exact same packagegroups are selected?

Comment: The package discrepancy sounds like a bug with Anaconda.   You may want to file a bug report at https://bugzilla.redhat.com

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking the list of extra packages and checking what type value those packages have in their respective groups in the repositories comps.xml file. I wonder if perhaps the UI and kickstart disagree over what 'type' of packages get installed when groups are selected (perhaps optional packages aren't selected by default by the UI but are selected by default by kickstart or something like that).